# How to freeze Ar Camera in middle of a session

Tags: android, augmented-reality, arcore, sceneform

I've developed a drawing application that uses ArCore and Sceneform to draw in the air.
Now I want to freeze the camera and draw on it without destroying or stopping the Ar Session.

Is it possible?
If yes, how can someone 'Freeze' the frame on ArCore/Sceneform.